# stat_summary_2d with geom="text"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot a heatmap of mean values. It is pretty straightforward.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=var1, y=var2, z=var3)+
stat_summary_2d(fun=“mean“,geom="tile")
```

I need a text above the tiles representing same values.

I tried,

```
 +stat_summary_2d(fun="mean", geom="text")
```

but it requires label aesthetic and I don't know what to write there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the computed variable at each cell with `..value..`. As you didn't provide data, below is an example using `diamonds` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, depth, z = price)) +
    stat_summary_2d(fun = 'mean') +
    stat_summary_2d(aes(label = ..value..), fun="mean", geom="text")
```